# IndexOutOfBoundsException on index 6 when Arrraylist size is 139

Tags: java, list, exception, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a class called A. iIn this class I have a  String name and a setter and getter for this String.
I also have a List that is being initialized as follows :

```
List<A>myList = ArrayList<A>(SomeOtherList);
```

Now when I check the size of my ArrayList I can see that the size of the list is 139 but when I try to get the value in index 6 I get

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6.`

But if I try to print the values from 0 - 138 in a for loop I will not get the Exception,

```
String name = myList.get(6).getName(); // Exception

for(int i = 0 ; i < 139 ; i++){
    System.out.println(myList.get(i).getName());
}//will work
```

Did anyone ever encounter this problem???

the for loop print all the 139 names to the console 
but when the code reach the line of the get function i get the flow exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
at com.icap.dashboard.DashboardPage.getSelectionFromCookie(DashboardPage.java:337)
at com.icap.dashboard.DashboardPage.addCCYPanelAndChannels(DashboardPage.java:149)
at com.icap.dashboard.DashboardPage.<init>(DashboardPage.java:107)
... 52 more
```

i compile my project using maven the initialized of the ArrayList is with a Collection Nanes

Comment: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6` => the size of myList is 6. Can you include a `System.out.println(myList.size());` right before the line where you get the exception?

Comment: You should probably use the debugger.

Comment: The exception is being thrown and terminating execution *before* reaching your for loop, hence the misconception that you don't receive an exception there.

Comment: Should we read that instead ? : `List<A> myList = new ArrayList<A>(SomeOtherList);`

Comment: Post the *exact* code that you claim works. Your current examples are clearly just typed in; the first assignment statement won't even compile. Also, give context: show the entire method.

Comment: Do you really hold 139 names in a cookie? And if your response to this is "what are you talking about," it should be a hint to you that the code you think is throwing isn't the code that's actually throwing.

Answer (score 1):

This works :

```
import java.util.*;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A> SomeOtherList = new ArrayList<A>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 139; i++) {
            SomeOtherList.add(new A().setName(String.valueOf(i)));
        }
        List<A> myList = new ArrayList<A>(SomeOtherList);

        System.out.println("random access: " + myList.get(6).getName());

        for(int i = 0 ; i < myList.size() ; i++){
            System.out.println(myList.get(i).getName());
        }

    }

    public static class A {
        String name;

        public A setName(String theName) { this.name = theName; return(this); }
        public String getName() { return(this.name); }
    }
}
```

Try to use this working example with your data.

Answer (score 0):

The error message speaks for itself: You are trying to get element 6 of an array containing only 6 elements. And, since array indices start at 0, the highest possible index you can ask for without getting an exception is 5.

Your code and description:

```
String name = myList.get(6).getName(); // Exception

for(int i = 0 ; i < 139 ; i++){
    System.out.println(myList.get(i).getName());
}//will work
```

is simply not possible, because the call

```
myList.get(6).getName();
```

will be made inside the for-loop. For the scenario you are describing to be possible, myList must be different in the two cases.